# Can a WebForms button access a class code-behind property via the aspx markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

From Web Form ASPX Markup

```
<tr>
    <td><asp:Label ID="monstersPrimaryWeaponDamageTotalLabel"  Text="Primary Weapon Damage: " runat="server" />
    </td>                
    <td><asp:Button ID="PrimaryWeaponDamageButton"
                     Text="Update Primary Weapon Damage"
                     ValidationGroup="MakeMonster"
                     runat="server"
                     OnClick="MonstersPrimaryWeaponDamageTotalString"
    </td>                 
    <td><%=MonstersPrimaryWeaponDamageTotalString%></td>
</tr>
```

From Code Behind

```
string monstersPrimaryWeaponDamageTotalString = " -NA- ";
public string MonstersPrimaryWeaponDamageTotalString
{
    get{return monstersPrimaryWeaponDamageTotalString;}
    set{monstersPrimaryWeaponDamageTotalString = value;}
}
```

Error from web browser (FireFox)

```
Compilation Error  
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
 required to service this request. 
 Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0118:  
 'MakeMonsters.MonstersPrimaryWeaponDamageTotalString' is a 'property' but is used like a 'method'

Source Error:

Line 860:                <td><asp:Label   ID="monstersPrimaryWeaponDamageTotalLabel" Text="Primary Weapon Damage: " runat="server" />
Line 861:                
Line 862:                <td><asp:Button ID="PrimaryWeaponDamageButton 
Line 863:                         Text="Update Primary Weapon Damage"
Line 864:                         ValidationGroup="MakeMonster"
```

In the error from the web browser it is highlighting line 862 as the problem. Although as you can see from the posted code from Visual Studio above that lines 862 - 864 are all part of the asp:button line.

What I am trying to do:
I have a webform that collects data for creating a character sheet in a roleplaying game. Then it writes that data to an XML file.

This is not a computer game, so don't think I can even begin to write that type of code. No, we play table top games the old fasion way, just I write the stories and am the GM (DM). All I am doing is putting my books in XML form so the players can access them from their laptops and phones. Saves lots of time and money from re-printing everything on paper. Not a computer program.

I am about halfway through and the XML file is created no problem.

Now, I want to modify the webform so that as I input certain data I can click a button next to certain fields that are calculated from various other fields and it displays the results for me in a separate blank field. The purpose of doing this is to see the results of what I have inputed so far before I finish the entire form and submit it to create the XML file.

Sorry I am not a professional. This is just hobby stuff, but have done a fair amount of reading on the Internet (just this forum and in Google), but probably do not know enough computer science theory to ask my question correctly to capture a useful answer.

Throw me some bones and I will try to edit my question and example code to be more useful to others seeking answers to this sort of thing.

The knowledge I am seeking is how to access the setter and getting from the webform. IE: what I want to do is click a button and have code behind do some calculations, string manipulation, and all that stuff, then store the result in a variable. Then, the webform will display the variable on the web page.

I am thinking my problem is understanding the whole, static, public, private, protected thing; but I have tried a dozen varieties of all that and just make a bigger mess.
As the error says I am trying to use a property as a method. Here is what I think I know about that.

A property is sort of like a variable (not sure the difference). Its designed to be a field in a database. In code behind, it behaves like a method (which in the old days before my hair got gray we called sub-routines, then functions). Properties, should be short and simple but can be accessed like methods - although I really don't see them as that similar.
A Method (is a function) and you can pass it quite a bit of data. Methods are for more complex needs, but they can be very simple.

Comment: `OnClick` is an event. It expects to have a method that will be called on click of that button. You giving it a property - not a method. The system does not know what to do with your property.

Comment: You don't have to write this lengthy question. Just state your issue

Comment: Hey Mike, did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an event handler to the button:

```
protected void Btn_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //yourCode
}
```

Your ASPX:

```
<asp:Button ID="PrimaryWeaponDamageButton"
                     Text="Update Primary Weapon Damage"
                     ValidationGroup="MakeMonster"
                     runat="server"
                     OnClick="Btn_OnClick" />
```

If this was not the issue, please clarify in your question

Comment: Only if he wants to cause a postback :)

Comment: It is now doing exactly what I was after.

Comment: OK, but I don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Page markup:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server">
    <%# _description %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdateDescription" runat="server" 
    Text="Update Description" OnClick="btnUpdateDescription_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class your_page : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string _description;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            _description = "descriptor";
            ph1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void btnUpdateDescription_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _description = "new description";
        ph1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem causing this error was not what I thought when I asked this question.

What I had been doing is converting all of my variables I declared outright:

For example like this

string railRoadTracks = "choo-choo";

into a more proper property set up with setters and getters

For example like this

private string railRoadTracks = "choo-choo";

public string RailRoadTracks

{

```
get{return railRoadTracks;}

set{railRoadTracks = value;}
```

}

When doing this Visual Studio offers to help by saving a bunch of re-typing and changing all the variables formally used as railRoadTracks to RailRoadTracks. It is merely and automated mass renaming function to  make sure your program is using the new propety.

Visual Studio pops up asking if you want this done or not when you create the new property. In my ignorance I did not know what this popup meant and told it no. I went and manually changed the variables (called properties in new programmer speak) I was working with at the time, and left others unchanged.
Also changing other parts of the program to use public and private variables, I screwed everything up and my web page was trying to access once public variables that had become private.
The solution was to go and modify the entire program to use all the same properties.